# SecurityServiceProvider - can't logout

Tags: php, security, symfony, silex

The login form works fine but the logout option doesn't 
Here is the code I use

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
 'security.firewalls' => array( 
  'admin' => array(
   'pattern' => '^/admin',
   'form' => array( 'login_path' => '/passport/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check' ),
   'logout' => array('logout_path' => 'admin/logout'),
    'users' => array(
    // raw password is foo
    'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
   ),
  ),
 )));
$app->run();
```

Then in one of the templates in the admin I have

```
 <a href="{{path('admin_logout')}}"> Log Out</a>
```

Which produce this url - /admin/logout

When I click on the link I get `Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/logout". The route is wrongly configured`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'logout' => array('logout_path' => 'admin/logout')
```

should be

```
'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout')
```

you missed a `/` in front of `/admin path`